# Angle between 2 pointers of a clock

Tags: geometry

What's the angle between the two pointers of the clock when time is 15:15? The answer I heard was 7.5 and i really cannot understand it. Can someone help? Is it true, and why?

Comment: The minute hand is horizontal, pointing to the right, so $0^\circ$, while the hour hand has gone $1/4$ of the way from the $3$ to the $4$, and the angle between these is $360^\circ/12=30^\circ$. One fourth of $30^\circ$ is $7.5^\circ$, so  the claim is correct.

Comment: When the BIG pointer is on 15:00, the SMALL pointer has passed 15:00 by $\frac{15}{60}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}$ of the arc between 15:00 and 16:00. But the arch between 15 and 16 is $\frac{360°}{12}=30°$. Hence the hour hand is $\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}\times 30° = 7.5°$ ahead of where the minute hand is.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a 12-hour clock, then the minute hand is at 3 and the hour hand is 1/4 of the way between 3 and 4. Thus the angle between them is $\frac14(\frac{360^{\circ}}{12})=7.5^{\circ}$.

(Note that the angle between two successive numbers on the face, like 3 and 4, is 1/12 of the full circle; that's where the $\frac{360^{\circ}}{12}$ comes from.)

Answer (score 1):

At 15:15, the minute hand is 90 degrees from 12.  The hour hand is $3+1/4= 13/4$ hours past 12, so the angle is $13/4$ out of $12$ hours.  So it's

$$\frac{13/4}{12} 360 = \frac{195}{2}.$$

The difference between the two angles is

$$\frac{195}{2} - 90 = \frac{15}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

At $15$ ie $3$ o' clock minute hand will be at exact $3$. Now for every minute the hour hand moves $0.5$ degrees . Calculation we have $360^o=12$hrs ie $360=12×60$minutes  thus $0.5deg/min $ hence the answer is $15\times 0.5=7.5$degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume we have a 12 hour clock and let 1200 hrs be 0 degrees and lets measure angles clockwise from there. At 1500 hrs, the hour hand is exactly on the three, that is at 90 degrees.

It takes the hour hand 12 hours to travel 360 degrees. That comes to 
$\dfrac{360^\circ}{12 \text{hrs}} = 30 \frac{\text{degrees}}{\text{hr}}$

So, at 1515 hrs, $\dfrac 14$ hr later, the minute hand will be at 90 degrees and the the hour hand will have moved 
$\left(\dfrac 14 \text{hr} \right)
 \left(30 \frac{\text{degrees}}{\text{hr}}\right) = 7.5 \, \text{degrees}$.

So the angle between the two hands will be 7.5 degrees.